# Finding for each point-feature in layer nearest point in other point-ayer over network

Tags: qgis, network, proximity, nearest-neighbor

I'm looking for a solution for following problem:

- given a point layer A (10.000 points)
- given a point layer B (15.000 points)
- given a line layer C, as network (waternetwork)

I want to have for each point in layer A the nearest point from layer B. That nearest distance must be counted over a network, layer C, and put in a new attribute column in layer A.

I have found some ideas using QNEAT3, but it processes the distances from all points from A to all points from B, which is a huge overload.

Comment: Why didn't you use QNEAT3 and filtered the result?

Comment: In my opinion QNEAT will need too much processing, I have around 20.000 points.. QNEAT, using 'OD Matrix from Points as table (n:n)' would make for each point 19999 lines (each point will be processed over each other point to give the distance to that point). 
That would then be done 20000 times, which gives me 19999*20000 lines in the matrix.. This seems not feasible.